# Problems with uploading my blog to pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, deployment

I have uploaded my blog to pythonanywhere. On my localhost everything is working fine, but on pythonanywhere it is not working. 
I configured pythonanywhere like i did on my localhost, installed everything (Tinymce is also installed), but im getting this Error:

```
 2019-05-16 12:24:14,263: Error running WSGI application
2019-05-16 12:24:14,264: ImportError: No module named 'tinymce'
2019-05-16 12:24:14,264:   File "/var/www/urosdobricic_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
2019-05-16 12:24:14,264:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-05-16 12:24:14,264: 
2019-05-16 12:24:14,265:   File "/home/UrosDobricic/.virtualenvs/urosdobricic.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-05-16 12:24:14,265:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-05-16 12:24:14,265: 
2019-05-16 12:24:14,265:   File "/home/UrosDobricic/.virtualenvs/urosdobricic.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2019-05-16 12:24:14,265:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2019-05-16 12:24:14,266: 
2019-05-16 12:24:14,266:   File "/home/UrosDobricic/.virtualenvs/urosdobricic.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2019-05-16 12:24:14,266:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2019-05-16 12:24:14,266: 
2019-05-16 12:24:14,266:   File "/home/UrosDobricic/.virtualenvs/urosdobricic.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2019-05-16 12:24:14,266:     module = import_module(entry)
```

I have installed Tinymce with pip3 install django-tinymce --user, like i did on my localhost.
Can´t figure out what is happening.

If i go to the .virtualenvs and try to install it then it says:

```
10:50 ~/.virtualenvs $ pip3 install django-tinymce --user
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Requirement already satisfied: django-tinymce in /home/UrosDobricic/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.8.0)
```

So everything is installed fine.

Comment: I see that pythonanywhere is looking into .virtualenvs.
The actual folder where everything is, is not there.
How do i change the path? Or is this path ok for the package tinymce?
The path where the whole project is, is at 
/home/UrosDobricic/urosdobricic.pythonanywhere.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd`ing into the `~/.virtualenvs` directory does not change where the package is installed.

Use the link on the web app page to open a console with the virtualenv activated and don't use the `--user` option when installing.

Comment: I used the --user because the bash console told me so. I´m opening the bash with the link given on the dashboard. Is that correct?

Comment: That does not apply when using a virtualenv. Use the link to the virtualenv console on your web app configuration page, not the dashboard.

Comment: No, it won´t work.
The same again. 
I deleted everything and tried with your method.
I dont understand what is happening.
Can you please check my github to see if all files are ok?
I think everything is ok, because it is working on my localhost.

https://github.com/UrosDobricic/blog.git

Comment: Ok guys, i solved my problem.
The problem was the path in the pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py file.